# COM instance (invoked from PHP)

Tags: php

```
$XL = new COM("Excel.Application");
```

...creates a new instance of Excel.

But I want to interact with an existing one.  (In the olden days, Microsoft VB term of art was GetObject() vis-à-vis CreateObject().)

PHP is being instructed in the statement above to do the equivalent of CreateObject().  How can it be instructed to do GetObject() instead?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for, but this is hte function style code, not the OOP style code:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-get-active-object.php